# Weird Viewport render issue

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am new to blender. I was trying to render the default cube which appears when we open a new project but whenever I render it, it shows some weird outlines on the object. I have tried this with eevee engine.
But, it appears well in the other three modes.

**Render Mode:-**

[image: Render Mode-]

**Other Mode:-**

[image: Other Mode:-]

**Edit:-**

After a deeper dive into the settings and blender, I found that the issue is somewhat releated to alpha and color rendering.
Some of the screenshots are below:-

**1- Alpha and color mode:**

[image: Render mode Alpha and color mode]

**2-Alpha mode:-**

[image]

**3- Color mode:-**

[image]

***Note: These screenshots which are shared after edit are of the actual render window and the previous ones are of my viewport render mode***

Please help me with configuring blender settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, you should make sure your graphics card fits the minimum requirements and update your drivers

Comment: My processor is intel core i5 6th generation with no graphics card. Laptop is Lenovo idea pad 300 17isk. Will it work with blender

Comment: Here are the recommended configurations : https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ As you can see, you need at least a graphics card for the minimum requirement

Comment: So, isn't there any alternative for that?  Anything which will make it work?

Comment: But, I don't think it to be the cause as if my system doesn't meets the requirements, then blender would have given an error while installing it. But, it works fine until I don't choose the viewport render mode

Comment: Sorry, but this is definitiely caused by your Pc not meeting the requirements, especially because of the lack of graphics card. The rest might be up to par, explaining why you were able to launch the software successfully, but you will have trouble using the rendering engine with your specs

Comment: Please go through the above mentioned problem once again as I have added some more information in the "Edit" section. It might help you explain me the actual problem.

Comment: Hardware and configuration issue for sure.

Comment: But the alpha settings are doing ssomething wrong the color mode is rendering properly.

Comment: Hey! I did some changes in settings and don't know why but it resolves the issue. On turning on **Screen Space reflections** , resolves the issue. Also, turning on the **High bit depth** option resolves it too.

Comment: Please explain me why and will it be good in the long run?

Comment: You may be able to use Eevee for simple renders since it is primarily based on CPU and not GPU, but as you noticed you will get artifacts if you try to go too high in the settings. Also, I'm pretty sure you will have troubles with Cycles which is a "realistic" render engine whereas Eevee is a real-time rendering engine like the ones used in video games. If you manage to model as you wish with your current spec but can't render images or videos, you can use online "cloud" rendering services but they usually are not free

Comment: Ok.... But to tell you that cycles is working way too better than the eevee engine although being a bit slow, its render quality is much better than ever on my pc

Comment: And by the way thanks for helping me.